# Python3 print formatting

Tags: printing, python-3.6

I want to format the output from print function.

```
def main():
    print('1 2 3 4 5'*7)
    # Write code here 

main()

Required Output:
    1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4 5
    1 2 3 4 5
Obtained Output:
    1 2 3 4 51 2 3 4 51 2 3 4 51 2 3 4 51 2 3 4 51 2 3 4 51 2 3 4 5
```

How do I make print function in Python3 to perform this job?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the separator to be a linebreak.

```
print(*7*('1 2 3 4 5',), sep='\n')
```

Equivalently, you can add the linebreak at the end of the string and remove the end linebreak from `print`.

```
print(7*'1 2 3 4 5\n', end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print('1 2 3 4 5\n'*7)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
 print('1 2 3 4 5\n' * 7)

main()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**